# Restrict direct file access Nginx and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'm looking for a nice clean way to restrict access to direct files in my CodeIgniter PHP site, running on nginx.

I have some `.phar` and `.json` files floating around in the web-root and some files that won't be handled by CodeIgniter.

If I was to type the path of a `.php` file directly into the browser, I am using

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

to deny direct script access. However, an attacker could possibly map my directory structure this way (if say he/she figured out I was using CodeIgniter).

What I would like is a method to restrict access all from the web server (nginx in my case). Once in production, I know that there are only a few url segments that I intent for the users to use.

How do I restrict the access to only these in a nice extensible way, but still allow my assets to be retrieved freely?

### EDIT

I Basically want a way to protect myself if I did not include

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

at the top of a PHP script. That's what I meant my extensible. I figured there might be a good "one fits all" solution that I could apply to nginx.

Comment: Why don't you simply chmod the folders containing the files so they cannot be accessed publicly?

Comment: Why do these files need to be in the webroot if they aren't being used? I also second what @KevinFlorida says regarding chmod, just be careful that whatever does need access to them is running in the appropriate group.

Comment: Ok but what about PHP files that I might have missed the direct access denial statement?

Comment: PHP files are not a problem because they are interpreted before being sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

Put anything that should not be public (CodeIgniter for example) outside the public directory.

For example, if your root is `/var/www/htdocs` then put your stuff in `/var/www`, like `/var/www/codeigniter`. You can then drop an `index.php` file in `/var/www/htdocs` and include CodeIgniter from there.

Answer (score -1):

Use caution here.. I am not sure if you want your .json to be accessed via http request..

But here is how you can do it in your .htaccess file:

```
# Prevent direct access to certain filetypes and directories
<Files ~ "(\.(phar|json))$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

I strongly advise you simply place private files inside a directory which you can chmod so they cannot be accessed outside your application if that is what you want though.

Comment: ok thanks but I am using nginx - I want to know specifically for nginx (i.e. in nginx.conf). I will also chmod various files and place them above root.